# mvc .control class to model ,call two classes in php

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm still learning OOP so this might not even be possible (although I would be surprised if so), I need some help calling another classes method.

> This is codes in `control folder` that retrieved  details from view to store damaged book table and need to update book table status as "damaged". When I run the program both tables are not updated when run it. I need a big help to make this work.

**control/MarkDamagedBook.php**

```
include('../model/Books.php');

include('../model/DamagedBook.php');
$type=$_POST['type'];
if ($type=='save')
{ 
    $DamagedBook = new DamagedBook();
    $DamagedBook->book_id=$_POST["book_id"];
    $DamagedBook->member_id=$_POST["member_id"];
    $DamagedBook->damaged_type=$_POST["cmbpro"];
    $DamagedBook->damaged_desc=$_POST["reason"];
    $DamagedBook->penalty =$_POST["penalty"];
    $DamagedBook->reason_panalty =$_POST["reason_panalty"];
    $DamagedBook->save();

    $Books = new Books(); //create an object of Books class
    $Books->book_id=$_POST["book_id"];
    $Books->updateBook();//cal a function 


     header("Location: ../view/MarkDamagedBook/new.php"); 

    }
```

**../model/Books.php**    <  books class

```
include_once "db_connection.php";
class Books extends db_connection{

public $book_id;
public $status ;

function updateBook()
{
    $status ="damaged";
    $query ="UPDATE tbl_book SET status='$status' WHERE book_id='$this->book_id'";
    mysqli_query($this->con,$query);
}

}
```

**model/DamagedBook.php**

```
 <?php
include_once "db_connection.php";
class DamagedBook extends db_connection
{
public $book_id;
public $member_id;
public $damage_type;
public $damgbook_desc;
public $status ;

function save()
{
$query= "INSERT INTO tbl_damagebook(book_id,member_id,damage_type,damgbook_desc,penalty_type,penalty_reason)VALUES('$this->book_id','$this->member_id','$this->damaged_type','$this->damaged_desc','$this->penalty','$this->reason_panalty');";
mysqli_query($this->con,$query);
}
}
```

**db_connection.php**

```
<?php

class db_connection {
public $con;
private $_host = "localhost";
private $_username = "root";
private $_password = "";
private $_database = "librarysys";

public function __construct()
{
$this->con = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_database);
if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
trigger_error("Failed to connect to MySQL: ");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: The code is terrible, but it should work (except relative location in `header()` I think) -  at least the part you've shown. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script - some messages should apear (update your question if they do). Better learn some more OOP before refactoring is still possible. You could show it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - you'll get some hints.

Comment: dr, @shudder ,thanks for your help..but **header()** is work properly without  insertion and no any error massages  also.